# asp.net core authentication AddMicrosoftAccount

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have added microsoft authentication to my app as follows:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
                        options.Scope.Add("openid profile email");
                    });
```

I can't figure out how to request additional scopes, the above does not work as the claims for "profile" or "email" are never returned.

Does anyone know how to do this or if its possible?

Comment: Try adding each one as a separate call to .Add(). E.g. .Add("openid"), .Add("profile")...

Comment: try to remove `Scope.Add` at all? `MicrosoftAccountOptions` contains *https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read* scope by default.

Comment: and then you have to look for `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress`, `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name` instead of the short `email`, `displayName` etc. that's a really old MS handler, (imo) moved into Core for backward compatibility with ws-fed and owin

Answer (score 2):

`MicrosoftAccountOptions` contains `graph.microsoft.com/user.read` scope by default, so after finishing the flow your `Identity` should have user information without any additional tricks. However `AddMicrosoftAccount` is actually `AddOAuth` with a specific preset and can be treated obsolete. By that reason it can't give you the `openid` scope.

Up to date alternative is to use OpenId Connect. You can add it directly, [as it was presented in Identityserver samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/f0d57a3c0fd231b1a5e270783536a8e15d05c4d8/src/IdentityServer4/host/Startup.cs#L167-L183), or use the specialized extension from MS by getting the
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` package and following [this quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

There you can add the oidc scopes one by one:

```cs
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/"; // Microsoft identity platform
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants
        options.Scope.Add("email");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure out how to request additional scopes, the above does not work as the claims for "profile" or "email" are never returned.

`openid`, `email`, `profile`, and `offline_access` are `OpenID Connect` scopes . The problem is `AddMicrosoftAccount` is using `OAuth 2.0` code flow , not OpenID Connect. So that the scopes won't work .

When using `AddMicrosoftAccount` , it will set scope to `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` by default , that means it will get an access token which you could use to access user's basic information using Microsoft Graph , After redirecting back to your application from Microsoft Login page , the extension will send a http post request with access token to Microsoft Graph endpoint(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) to get user's information and create authecation ticket , see source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authentication/MicrosoftAccount/src/MicrosoftAccountHandler.cs#L24) .

If you want to use `Openid Connect` , you should use [AddOpenIdConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.openidconnectextensions.addopenidconnect?view=aspnetcore-2.2) extension . And if you are using Azure AD , you'd better use Openid Connect .